# Notifications not shown when the app is active or closed

Tags: android, push-notification, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
Device Info:Xiomi Redmi 4
Android: 7.1.2 N2G47H
MIUI: 9.1.1.0
```

When using these plugins : [`Scheduled Notifications`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scheduled_notifications), [`Local Notifications`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/local_notifications), [`Firebase Cloud Messaging`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_messaging),  notifications work correctly. But there are a few cases where notifications are not shown :

1. If the App is not yet opened,
2. If the App is opened and I'm using the App
3. If I killed the App

How can I show notifications even in these situations?

Comment: firebase_messaging should show them when the app is not active. The structure of the message might be wrong if it doesn't. `scheduled_notification` and `local_notification` should show the notification when the app is active. Does your app even receive the notification when the app is active (open in foreground)?

Comment: I improved a bit the quality of your question. You shouldn't include things such as "I asked tons of peoples but nobody answer" as it doesn't provide any helpful information.

Comment: FCM shows the previously(beofe 10 mins) sent  notifications,only when i open the app,but whatsapp or other android apps in my phone are showing notifications even without opening the app(ie.. those whatsapp and other apps are not yet opened after the reboot,but they fetching for new notifications,but my flutter app does nothing),THIS IS APPLICABLE FOR BOTH THE FCM AND LOCAL NOTIFICATIONS TOO

Comment: @RémiRousselet yes thnks,sometimes i get into emotional,tht no one is responding a newbie's questions